# How to format Letters in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex

After a long search and asking questions I managed to wright working code on miktex, that is compiled by XeLaTeX. Here is sample

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sylfaen}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={SimHei},ItalicFont={[SIMKAI.TTF]}]{SimSun}
\setCJKsansfont{SimHei}
\setCJKmonofont{[SIMFANG.TTF]}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhsong}{SimSun}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhhei}{SimHei}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhkai}{[SIMKAI.TTF]}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhfs}{[SIMFANG.TTF]}
\newcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}} % 宋体
\newcommand*{\heiti}{\CJKfamily{zhhei}}   % 黑体
\newcommand*{\kaishu}{\CJKfamily{zhkai}}  % 楷书
\newcommand*{\fangsong}{\CJKfamily{zhfs}} % 仿宋

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=2.5cm,  left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large$\thesection.$}{}{1mm}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalsize$\thesubsection.$}{}{1mm}{}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{7ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus 0.1ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{6ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus 0.1ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{} 
\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{\thepage } 
\rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Large\filcenter}{}{}{}

\newcommand{\Ceil}[1]{$\lceil\text{#1}\rfloor$}
\newcommand{\Stoke}[1]{$\left/\text{#1}\right/$}
\newcommand{\Over}[2]{$\overset{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}$}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{Sentence}[1]{
    \vspace{5pt}
    \textbf{წინადადებები:}
    \vspace{2pt}
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]
    \setlength\itemsep{1pt}
}{\end{enumerate}\vspace{4pt}}

\newenvironment{Word}[2]{
    \vspace{2pt}
    \textbf{სიტყვები:}
    \vspace{-7pt}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[#2]       
}{\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{-10pt}}  

\begin{document}

\small

\section{ფრაზები და სიტყვები}

\subsection{ფრაზები: ეს რა არის?}

\begin{Word}{3}{1.}
\item はい            --- დიახ
\item いいえ           --- არა
\item こんにちは     --- გამარჯობა
\item おはよう          --- დილა მშვიდობისა 
\item こんばんわ     --- საღამო მშვიდობისა
\item おやすみなさい       --- ღამე მშვიდობისა 

\item さようなら     --- ნახვამდის 
\item ありがとう     --- მადლობა 
\item すみません     --- უკაცრავად 
\item てきすと      --- სახელმძღვანელო 
\item ひこうき      --- აეროპორტი

\item 何 \Ceil{なに}       --- რა
\item 誰 \Ceil{だれ}       --- ვინ/ვინმე
\item 車 \Ceil{くるま}  --- მანქანა
\item 傘 \Ceil{かさ}       --- ქოლგა 

\item 椅子 \Ceil{いす}  --- სკამი
\item 鉛筆 \Ceil{えんぴつ}    --- ფანქარი 
\item 新聞 \Ceil{しんぶん}    --- გაზეთი 
\end{Word}

\begin{Sentence}{1)}
\item これは\Over{なん}{何}ですか。 \Stoke{kore wa nan desu ka}--- ეს რა არის?
\item あれは何ですか。 \Stoke{are wa nan desu ka}--- ის რა არის?
\item それはカメラですか。 \Stoke{sore wa kamera desu ka}--- არის ეს კამერა?
\item これもカメラですか。 \Stoke{kore mo kamera desu ka}--- ესეც კამერაა?
\item これは\Over{だれ}{誰}のですか。 \Stoke{kore wa dare no desu ka}--- ეს ვისია?
\item それはいすです。 \Stoke{sore wa isu desu}--- ეს არის სკამი.
\item これもカメラです。 \Stoke{kore mo kamera desu}--- ეს არის ასევე კამერა.
\item いいえ、それはカメラではありません。 \Stoke{iie, sore wa kamera dewa arimasen}--- არა, ეს კამერა არ არის.
\item はい、それはカメラです。 \Stoke{hai, sore wa kamera desu}--- დიახ, ეს კამერა არის.
\item どうもありがとうございます。 \Stoke{doumo arigatou gozaimasu}--- დიდი მადლობა.\\
\end{Sentence}

თუ დავაკვირდებით პირველ წინადადებას 何 იეროგლიფს თავზე აწერია ჰირაგანაზე, თუ როგორ იკითხება. ასეთი ჩანაწერი ხშირად გამოიყენება.\\

あ, い, う  --- ზოგჯერ გაომიყენება მისი წინა ასოს გასაორმაგებლად.\\

これ   --- გამოიყენება, როცა ობიეკტი მთხრობელთან არის ახლოს;\\
それ   --- გამოიყენება, როცა ობიეკტი მსმენელთან არის ახლოს;\\
あれ   --- გამოიყენება, როცა ობიეკტი არცერთთან არის ახლოს.\\

は --- იეროგლიფი, როცა ზოგჯერ იკითხება როგორც \Stoke{wa};\\
か --- თხრობითი წინადება გადაყავს კითხვითში;\\
も --- გამოიყენება, როცა გვინდა ვთქვათ „ასევე“.\\

ou --- იკითხება, როგორც გრძელი „ო“, მაგალითად \Stoke{arigat\underline{ou}} -- მადლობა;\\
ii --- იკითხება, როგორც გრძელი „ი“, მაგალითად \Stoke{\underline{ii}e} -- არა;\\
ei --- იკითხება, როგორც გრძელი „ე“, მაგალითად \Stoke{sens\underline{ei}} -- მასწავლებელი.\\

\end{document}
```

However I cannot use bold, italics and other to format text. Generally for Georgian documents I use pdflatex compiler and by following lines

```
\input{glyphtounicode} 
\pdfgentounicode=1 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T8K,T8M]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,georgian]{babel}
```

the text can be formatted as well as english, and \hyphenation are done automatically. Can I use it in XeLaTeX? Because the code as it is now does not do any text format and automatic \hyphenation and so document is very plain.

Comment: Do you have a bold version of Sylfaen installed, for example? `book` doesn't support `8pt` by the way.

Comment: where can I check it? T8K,T8M fonts can not be used?

Comment: It will certainly be *easier* with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I'm pretty sure that it can be done with (pdf)LaTeX. (Probably.) But it is likely to be a lot more hassle. Unless you have really compelling reason to stick to (pdf)LaTeX, Xe/LuaLaTeX is your best option.

Comment: miktex doesn't support CJK as well as texlive, so I was not able to find working code for miktex to be compiled in pdflatex.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be but I know nothing about MikTeX. But even with TeX Live, Xe/LuaTeX will be easier for this than (pdf)TeX. As for checking whether you have e.g. bold Sylfaen, I don't know that either. How do you normally see what fonts you have installed on Windows? It is using system fonts, so there's nothing TeX-specific here: it is just how to do this for your OS with your desktop etc.

Comment: I normally work with pdflatex, so I don't use \setfont or something like that. In Control Panel->Fonts I have Sylfaen. I am not interested in a spasific compiler. However, if you don't know miktex, you won't be able to answer my question. I have a working version of it for pdflatex wich runs on texlive and not on mitex.